# Microsoft SQL Server JPA Stored Procedure com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{'

Tags: java, sql-server, jpa, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have a Microsoft SQL Server TSQL stored procedure

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_get_latest_ids]
@tblNm VARCHAR(50),
@ver VARCHAR(50)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @stmt VARCHAR(100)
SET @stmt = 'SELECT id FROM CHANGETABLE(CHANGES [DatabaseName].[dbo].[' +
@tblNm + '], ' + @ver + ') as c;';
EXEC (@stmt)
END
GO
```

This SP is working, I'm seeing rows returned when I run it like

```
exec  [dbo].[sp_get_latest_ids] @tblNm = 'Reports', @ver = '22379091'
```

Now I'm trying to use this Stored Proc with JPA as a StoredProcedureQuery in my DAO class

```
String selectStatement = "EXEC [dbo].[sp_get_latest_ids] @tblNm = 'Reports', @ver = '" + lastVer.toString()  + "'";
System.out.println(selectStatement);
StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery(selectStatement);
q.setMaxResults(100);

boolean isResultSet = q.execute(); // returns true when we have a result set from the proc
//List<Integer> reportIds2 =  q.getResultList();
```

This is not working, I get a stack trace that looks like below.  Need input on how to fix at this point, as '}' is not anywhere in my stored procedure code.  Thank you.

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_get_latest_changetable_ids] @tblNm = 'Reports', @ver = '22379091'
2017-04-03 16:50:21.800  WARN 15436 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 102, SQL
State: S0001
2017-04-03 16:50:21.802 ERROR 15436 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Incorrect syntax ne
ar '{'.
2017-04-03 16:50:21.809  INFO 15436 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled
.
2017-04-03 16:50:21.826 ERROR 15436 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup
 failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:779) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.
jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE
.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEAS
E.jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:1
.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:
1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar!/:
1.5.1.RELEASE]
        at com.company.railagentmonitor.Application.main(Application.java:41) [classes!/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [RailAgentMonitor-0.1.0.jar:na
]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [RailAgentMonitor-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [RailAgentMonitor-0.1.0.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [RailAgentMonitor-0.1.0.jar:na]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableSt
atement.getMoreResults
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692) ~[hibernate-enti
tymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-enti
tymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:224) ~[hibernate-en
titymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityMana
gerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.6.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.execute(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at com.company.railagentmonitor.dao.ChangetableVersionsDAOImpl.getLatestChangetableIds(ChangetableVersionsDAOImpl
.java:50) ~[classes!/:na]
        at com.company.railagentmonitor.service.ChangetableVersionsServiceImpl.getLatestChangetableIds(ChangetableVersion
sServiceImpl.java:24) ~[classes!/:na]
        at com.company.railagentmonitor.Application.run(Application.java:58) [classes!/:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:776) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.
jar!/:1.5.1.RELEASE]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Error calling CallableStatement.getMoreResults
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:106) ~[hi
bernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
 ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibern
ate-core-5.0.11
.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.convert(OutputsImpl.java:79) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.
0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.result.internal.OutputsImpl.<init>(OutputsImpl.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0
.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureOutputsImpl.<init>(ProcedureOutputsImpl.java:32) ~[hibernate-core-5
.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.buildOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:411) ~[hibernate-core-
5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl.getOutputs(ProcedureCallImpl.java:363) ~[hibernate-core-5.
0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.outputs(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:234) ~[hibernate-en
titymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.StoredProcedureQueryImpl.execute(StoredProcedureQueryImpl.java:217) ~[hibernate-en
titymanager-5.0.11.Final.jar!/:5.0.11.Final]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '{'.
        at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:232) ~[mssql-jd
bc-6.1.0.jre8.jar!/:na]
```

Comment: Shouldn't `createStoredProcedureQuery` only take the **name** of the stored procedure? It is probably converted to the JDBC call escape, which triggers the syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the docs at
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html
 the argument to createStoredProcedureQuery should be the name of the stored procedure, not a statement to execute the query.  Try:

```
StoredProcedureQuery q = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("sp_get_latest_ids");
```

Then bind your tblNm and ver parameters using the setParameter(...) methods of the resulting stored procedure query.

Regarding the "{" - my guess is that the `q.execute()` is building a query which has that character, but because your stored procedure 'name' is invalid, you get a syntax error after the character.